# How can I form this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> When the professionalism of the marketing increases, customers will
> feel that (or like) the product is greater.

I need to say this sentence in a more native way. After reading about "the more ... the more" role, I feel like it could be better than the previous sentence. But I still don't know how to construct it.

> The more professional your marketing is, the greater your product is.

But I actually didn't mean that the product will be greater. The product is the same. It is just a feeling of the customer but I don't know how to add it to the sentence. Here are my trials and let me know which one is correct please.

- The more professional your marketing is, **the greater your product they feel.**
- The more professional your marketing is, **they feel the greater your product is.**
- The more professional your marketing is, **the more they feel great about your product.**
- The more professional your marketing is, **the greater they feel about your product.**

We don't have to use "the more" role. So, please feel welcomed if you have any other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

1

> The more professional your marketing is, the greater your product they feel.

2

> The more professional your marketing is, they feel the greater your product is.

3

> The more professional your marketing is, the more they feel great about your product.

4

> The more professional your marketing is, the greater they feel about your product.

The pronoun **they** does not have a defined antecedent, and is suggested to be replaced with **customers** if terms like these are to be used.

For readability, based on the word sequencing of the first part of the sentence, 'the more professional (adj) your marketing (noun) is', example 1 has my preferred format.

I suggest a slight change to the sentence.

1a

> The more professional your marketing is, the greater your product [**is perceived**].